# Getting an error when using jQuery's click event

Tags: jquery

there. I'm using jQuery to add a click handler to some buttons I'm using for a calendar, but the context doesn't seem to matter much. I've tried putting anything (or nothing) in the function that's called by the click event.

If I click the button a few (three or four) times in succession, I get an error. It doesn't actually seem to affect the execution of the function itself. It just throws an error, which concerns me, obviously.

The code in question is as follows:

`$("#backward").click(function(event){. . .});`

And the error I'm getting is:

```
Error in event handler for 'undefined': INDEX_SIZE_ERR: DOM Exception 1 Error: Index or size was negative, or greater than the allowed value.
at J (chrome-extension://mgijmajocgfcbeboacabfgobmjgjcoja/content_js_min.js:14:142)
at null.<anonymous> (chrome-extension://mgijmajocgfcbeboacabfgobmjgjcoja/content_js_min.js:17:184)
at chrome-extension://mgijmajocgfcbeboacabfgobmjgjcoja/content_js_min.js:1:182
at miscellaneous_bindings:286:9
at chrome.Event.dispatchToListener (event_bindings:379:21)
at chrome.Event.dispatch_ (event_bindings:365:27)
at chrome.Event.dispatch (event_bindings:385:17)
at Object.chromeHidden.Port.dispatchOnMessage (miscellaneous_bindings:253:22) event_bindings:369
chrome.Event.dispatch_ event_bindings:369
chrome.Event.dispatch event_bindings:385
chromeHidden.Port.dispatchOnMessage miscellaneous_bindings:253
```

Obviously, the problem is with that extension, which is just [Google Dictionary](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-dictionary-by-goog/mgijmajocgfcbeboacabfgobmjgjcoja).

I'm not sure if the problem is with me or with that, but I'd prefer for my website not to clash with Google Dictionary...

Thanks!

Comment: Setup an example on http://jsfiddle.net/. I have this extension as well and I've never seen this happen.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ReZTK/

Not the best example. [Here](http://ec2-50-16-152-8.compute-1.amazonaws.com/~ben/module4/calendar.html) is the website I'm actually working on.

Comment: Yep, I get this error as well. Seems like a bug with the extension. I'd submit a bug report to Google.

Comment: It just happens when double-clicking a `<button>` element - no jQuery or anything required. I digged a little bit into the code, and it seems the extension cancels the translation functionality when double-clicking input/textarea elements. But they forgot to include `<button>` elements - double-clicking such elements doesn't actually make for a text selection, so their code getting the selected text fails.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it's clashing with something else you can always use:

```
$("#backward").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    . . .
});
```

Comment: This solves the chrome extension error message. How do I then use jQuery/javascript to complete the disabled default behaviour that clicking on a radio would have followed?

Comment: $("#backward").attr("checked", "checked");