# Error in event handler: IndexSizeError

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am getting following error in Chrome when double clicking on button, and then it doesn't work properly, by passing to another step not the next step I have defined.

How I can prevent this.

```
Error in event handler: IndexSizeError: Index or size was negative, or greater than the   allowed value.
```

Thank you

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104177/getting-an-error-when-using-jquerys-click-event